# Unity IOS Xcode Build Error: directory not found for option

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, chartboost

I am building a game in Xcode that I built in Unity3D, and I always get Build Failed because of the error

```
directory not found for option 'L/Users/bhaskarmishra/Documents/Arcade Master IOS Build/LibrariesPlugins/iOS'
```

which causes the error

```
library not found for -lChartboost
```

I think the reason for this is that its trying to find the Chartboost library which is in Build/Libraries/Plugins/iOS, but its looking for the directory Build/LibrariesPlugins/iOS which doesn't exist. The "/" in the middle of Libraries and Plugins seems to be missing.

I built this project directly from Unity3D so I am not sure why I'm getting this error or how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

In case its important, I built this project using Unity on Windows and then transferred the Xcode project to a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to test I tried building the project on Unity on Mac and that ended up working, so I guess the solution is to build the Unity Project on Mac.